# Automate a selection of multiple values from a multi-select list box UFT web app

Tags: web, automation, vbscript, multi-select, hp-uft

I am having a case where in a web based application I have to automate a selection of multiple values from a multi-select list box and then keep them as a result. I am struggling how to do that. I am getting error message "object required"->

```
Dim list, arrayRepIDs, i

list = Browser("").Page("").WebList("").GetROProperty("all items")

arrayRepIDs=split(list,",")

For i=0 to UBound(arrayRepIDs)

    If(arrayRepIDs.Selected)= true Then
    Msgbox "You selected..."
    End if

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're getting the error on the `If` line (in the future try to give as much information in the question as possible). The `arrayRepIds` is an array of strings but you're accessing its (non-existent) `.Selected` property. You also seem to think you're iterating through the array but you're not using the index `i`, rather you're doing the same thing on each iteration.

Instead of using `GetROProperty("all items")` you should be using `GetROProperty("selection")`.

See which properties are available [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2022/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/Web_WebList_Properties.htm).